# Xamarin.Forms Android app crashes after back navigation at webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-webview

in my Xamarin.Android App I'm having a webview. When open a website inside the webview, a view with a back button opens. When I click this back button too fast, the app crashes with the following message. But I don't know how to debug it, because it is only external code and I don't know, which object is null. For the webview I use the Xam.Plugin.webView NuGet package.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xam.Plugin.WebView.Droid.FormsWebViewClient.OnPageFinished (Android.Webkit.WebView view, System.String url) [0x000b8] in C:\Users\ryan.dixon\Source\Repos\Xam.Plugin.Webview\Xam.Plugin.WebView.Droid\FormsWebViewClient.cs:151
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <19853c43ab794d18ab1a33ecb65b3c4d>:0
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.159.2/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/runner/runners/2.159.2/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/runner/runners/2.159.2/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-27/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.24(intptr,intptr)
```

WebView

```
public void PerformBack()
{
    GoBack();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by click this back button too fast, you click the button when the webview is loading?

Comment: Yes, exactly this way!

Comment: Can you share more code to reproduce the problem? What is the back button, the default on the navigationbar or a custom button? It would be better if you can share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Forms webview, then you have to include the following

**Add the following in the view constructor after InitializeComponent();**

```
yourBackButton.Clicked += OnBackButtonClicked;
yourForwardButton.Clicked += OnForwardButtonClicked;
```

**Then, add the following events methods of course outside the constructor:**

```
async void OnBackButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (webView.CanGoBack)
    {
        webView.GoBack();
    }
    else
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}

void OnForwardButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (webView.CanGoForward)
    {
        webView.GoForward();
    }
}
```

Where webView is the name of your webView object.

For more information, please refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Thank you.